# Low-voltage LED light strip through wall to outlet - Allowed?

Tags: electrical, led, nec, low-voltage

I am installing some cabinets in my basement media room. I'd like to use a [Philips Hue Lightstrip](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-and-color-ambiance-lightstrip-plus-base-v4-80-inch/046677555337) for accent lighting. The other side of the wall on which the cabinets are mounted is unfinished - it's a utility room, bare studs, easily accessed by a standard door. There is an existing outlet on the unfinished side of the wall.

Is it permissible to pass the power cord for the light strip through a port in the wall to the outlet in the other room? I'd like to conceal everything except the light strip itself.

Generally, I understand what the NEC says about running cords through walls - don't! There's some grey areas here I'm unsure about.

1. The Hue Light transformer (plug) lists an output voltage of 24V, the same as "low voltage" wiring for items like doorbells and thermostats, which run through walls all the time. It's unclear to me how NEC applies to low voltage.
2. This isn't a substitute for "permanent wiring". It's a lamp with a plug. The plug even says "portable luminaire" right on it, which is a specifically listed exemption in NEC 400.
3. This also doesn't seem any different to me than a microwave or dishwasher with a cord running through a cabinet, which has been in every house I have ever owned.
4. The cord isn't fished in a wall packed full of insulation, which is obviously dangerous. The cord runs through the wall perpendicular, meaning it's only "in the wall" for the 1/2 inch thickness of the wall, and is free and visible in a room on the other side.
5. I'm not clear what danger is presented by the plug being in another room. I have a router plugged into the other outlet of the receptacle right now. I can't see it from outside the room, either, but I'm not worried about it.

Beyond a potential code violation which is easily rectified in about 5 minutes by unplugging and removing the light strip, is there a true danger here I am not recognizing? I don't see any more danger than presented by anything else currently plugged in the utility room.

EDIT: I get there are horrible things people *could* do passing a cord through a wall, which is why the rules exist. What I don't understand is how this particular situation is any different than a cord behind a bookcase, or through a cable grommet on a desk top?

Comment: Can you provide us with the markings on the cable itself?

Comment: There are two sections of cable. Cable 1: "E319028 RU(?) AWM STYLE 2464 80C 300V 20AWG VW-1 RONGCHUN", Cable 2: "STYLE 2725 80C 30V 24AWG VW-1 RONGCHUN", AC/DC Transformer: "Output 24.0V 0.83A 20.0W"

Comment: Just to clarify, this is the low voltage cable you're poking through the drywall, right?

Comment: Right. As far as I can tell, it's all low voltage from the point it leaves the AC adapter. The AC adapter and plug are a single unit.

Comment: I believe anything under 50 Volts is not subject to the NEC. So just the power supply and its input matters.